# Disabled form fields style in Windows 7

Tags: css, windows-7, browser

I just recently upgraded to Windows 7 and I have noticed that styling for text form fields across all browsers is non-existent. With Windows XP it was very obvious which form fields were disabled, but now I can't tell.

Are there any style settings I could use to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are just talking about it as a user, then this question belongs to Superuser

Comment: yup. For some reason browsers in winxp provide better default styles for styling disabled text inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, following is a way to style disabled form elements:

```
[disabled]{
color:#8A8A8A;
background-color:#D5D5D5;
}
```

Comment: I initially did this, but it affected all inputs, so I just created a class for text-fields.

Comment: So a class for [disabled] property isn't it?